# How to correctly use stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource on NSURL

Tags: macos, cocoa, appstore-sandbox

A sandboxed App must use Security Scoped Bookmarks in order to save its file access privileges over restarts. The [NSURL docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) say:

> You must balance every call to the
>   startAccessingSecurityScopedResource 
>   method with a corresponding call to the stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource 
>   method

But I can't see from the docs if I must call the `stopAccessing` method on the exact same `NSURL` object that I obtained by resolving a bookmark. (Are these 'magic' NSURL-objects with special properties?)

I would like to call `stopAccessing` on new NSURL objects, generated from the file path. Of course these point to the same resource. But does it have the same effect?

How can I see if access to a `NSURL` resource has been stopped?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there is metadata in the `NSURL` object with some kind of token granting access to that resource.

I don't think what you're proposing is the suggested way of doing it, but give it a shot and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

"How can I see if access to a NSURL resource has been stopped?"

stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource is a void method, not boolean, and there seems to be no way to test the resource to see if it has been "stopped".

- (void)stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource

I conclude that you must keep track of it yourself.